# C# grouping String Array over more entries compromize G-Code

Tags: arrays, grouping

I have a problem. I want to compress this g-code. (The G-Code looks allways different.)
My array in the moment looks like this: (import from a file)

```
        ArrayList arrn = new ArrayList() 
        {
            "G3 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G3 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G2 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G2 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G3 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G3 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G2 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G2 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G3 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G3 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G1 X40,000 Y0,000 F3570",
            "G2 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G2 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G2 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G2 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G2 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G2 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000"
        };
```

Now I want to group it.
Insted of the first 4 raws, I want to give a name like Group1

```
            "G3 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G3 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G2 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G2 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000"
```

The same I want to do with this group.

```
            "G2 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G2 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y-15,000 Z-15,000",
            "G3 X15,000 Y15,000 Z-15,000"
```

Then in the end I want to have an array like this:

```
            "Group1 2 times"
            "G3 X10,000 Y-10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G3 X10,000 Y10,000 Z-10,000",
            "G1 X40,000 Y0,000 F3570",
            "Group2 3 times"
```

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks for your help :)

Vazili